# Javapcript Proxy executando .get() em vez de .set()

Tags: javascript

Eu escrevi o seguinte código mínimo:

```
const greetings = new Proxy(
  {
    english: {
      well: "Hello ",
      come: "World!"
    },
    portuguese: {
      bem: "Ola",
      bindo: "Mundo!"
    }
  },
  {
    get: (ctx, key) => {
      console.log("Getter called");
      return ctx[key];
    },
    set: (ctx, key, val) => {
      console.log("Setter called");
      ctx[key] = val;
    }
  }
);

greetings.english.well = "Hola"; // (1)
greetings.english.come = "Mundo"; // (2)

console.log(`English wellcome :: ${greetings.english.well} ${greetings.english.come}`);
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
Getter called // (3)
Getter called // (4)
Getter called
Getter called
Wellcome :: Hola Mundo
```

Com a intenção de observar os funcionamentos dos getters e setters da nova funcionalidade Proxy().

E ela até funciona bem, DESDE QUE o target tenha apenas um nível de hierarquia.

Mas quando um objecto é colocado dentro do outro, tal como `well` e `come` é colocado dentro de `english`, aí dá problema.

O PROBLEMA:

Eu esperava que a linha de código `(1)` e `(2)` executasse o método `.set()` do `Proxy`. Porém, está executando o `.get()`, tal como é observável no log do console.

O ESPERADO:

Eu esperava que o log `(3)` e `(4)` imprimisse: `Setter called`, com S de set, e não com G de get.

Isso acontece porque o `Proxy` não observa que na linha `(1)` e `(2)` invoca-se um set e não um get.

Tem como contornar isso?

Answer (score 2):

não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas antes de qualquer coisa eu vou fazer uma modificação em seu código, para visualizar o melhor o que está acontecendo com ele.

O que vou fazer é uma modificação dentro dos métodos assessores(traps) `get` e `set` de forma a mostrar sobre o que eles estão sendo aplicados:

modificação em `get`:

```
   get: (ctx, key) => {
      console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
      return ctx[key];
   }
```

modificação em `set`:

```
   set: (ctx, key, val) => {
      console.log(`${key} Setter called`);
      ctx[key] = val;
   }
```

De forma a exibir qual a propriedade em que eles atuam:

```js
const greetings = new Proxy(
  {
    english: {
      well: "Hello ",
      come: "World!"
    },
    portuguese: {
      bem: "Ola",
      bindo: "Mundo!"
    }
  },
  {
    get: (ctx, key) => {
      console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
      return ctx[key];
    },
    set: (ctx, key, val) => {
      console.log(`${key} Setter called`);
      ctx[key] = val;
    }
  }
);

greetings.english.well = "Hola"; // (1)
greetings.english.come = "Mundo"; // (2)

console.log(`English wellcome :: ${greetings.english.well} ${greetings.english.come}`);
```

Como pode ver ao executar o código o resultado é:

```
english Getter called
english Getter called
english Getter called
english Getter called
English wellcome :: Hola Mundo
```

O que significa que quando faz as linhas:

```
greetings.english.well = "Hola"; 
greetings.english.come = "Mundo";
```

O método `set` para a propriedade `english` é chamado duas vezes.
E quando faz a linha:

```
console.log(`English wellcome :: ${greetings.english.well} ${greetings.english.come}`);
```

O método `set` para a propriedade `english` é chamado mais duas vezes.

Segundo o manual do objeto [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) estão definidos os métodos de acesso para as propriedades `english` e `portuguese` de seu objeto. Porém as subpropriedades de `english` e `portuguese` não são abrangidas pelos traps definidos no proxy pois mesmo estando aninhado são objetos diferentes do qual o `Proxy` é aplicado

Se quer definir também métodos de acesso para as propriedades de `english` e `portuguese` também crie proxies para esses objetos:

```js
const greetings = new Proxy({
  english: new Proxy({
    well: "Hello ",
    come: "World!"
  }, {
    get: (ctx, key) => {
      console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
      return ctx[key];
    },
    set: (ctx, key, val) => {
      console.log(`${key} Setter called to value ${val}`);
      ctx[key] = val;
    }
  }),
  portuguese: new Proxy({
    bem: "Ola",
    bindo: "Mundo!"
  }, {
    get: (ctx, key) => {
      console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
      return ctx[key];
    },
    set: (ctx, key, val) => {
      console.log(`${key} Setter called to value ${val}`);
      ctx[key] = val;
    }
  })
}, {
  get: (ctx, key) => {
    console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
    return ctx[key];
  }/*, 
     //O setter aqui foi cometado pois parece ser desnecessário
     //pois as propriedades que sefrerão modificações serão well, come, bem e bindo
  set: (ctx, key, val) => {
    console.log(`${key} Setter called`);
    ctx[key] = val;
  }*/
});

greetings.english.well = "Hola";
greetings.english.come = "Mundo";

console.log(`English wellcome :: ${greetings.english.well} ${greetings.english.come}`);
```

**Problema da verbosidade:**

Como foi comentado essa implementação de proxies aninhados é de difícil leitura e propícia a ocultação de erros. Uma alternativa é voltar com o `set` comentado no fragmento anterior e fazer a implementação de `english` e `portuguese` a parte da implementação de `greetings`.

```js
const english = new Proxy({
  well: "Hello ",
  come: "World!"
}, {
  get: (ctx, key) => {
    console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
    return ctx[key];
  },
  set: (ctx, key, val) => {
    console.log(`${key} Setter called to value ${val}`);
    ctx[key] = val;
  }
});

const portuguese = new Proxy({
  bem: "Ola",
  bindo: "Mundo!"
}, {
  get: (ctx, key) => {
    console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
    return ctx[key];
  },
  set: (ctx, key, val) => {
    console.log(`${key} Setter called to value ${val}`);
    ctx[key] = val;
  }
})

const greetings = new Proxy({
  english: {},
  portuguese: {}
}, {
  get: (ctx, key) => {
    console.log(`${key} Getter called`);
    return ctx[key];
  },
  set: (ctx, key, val) => {
    console.log(`${key} Setter called`);
    ctx[key] = val;
  }
});

greetings.english = english;
greetings.portuguese = portuguese;


greetings.english.well = "Hola";
greetings.english.come = "Mundo";

console.log(`English wellcome :: ${greetings.english.well} ${greetings.english.come}`);
```

Comment: Eu entendi! Mas um Proxy dentro de outro parece bem verboso e complicado. Fazer o que. É o que tem, né...

Comment: Sim é bem verboso, uma alternativa é voltar com o setter, que foi comentado, e implementar os objetos a parte.

Comment: @JHenry de uma olhada na edição que fiz.